# How can you cut a triangle from div with shadow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I need to cut triangle shape on both sides of my cards that have a shadow and effect on hover

[This](https://codepen.io/nikigan/pen/WNNdwzg) is what i have tried already

```
&__left-cut {
      box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      border-radius: 2px;
      position: absolute;
      width: 12px;
      height: 12px;
      left: 0;
      top: 50%;
      margin-top: -6px;
      margin-left: -7px;
      background-color: $bg-color;
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      transition: border .5s;

      &::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        width: 12px;
        height: 12px;
        transform: translate(-4px, -4px);
        left: 0;
        top: 50%;
        background-color: $bg-color;
      }
    }
```

I have to get this result 
[expected result](https://i.imgur.com/XBd9ooN)
My shadow is not looking too good.

Answer (score 0):

Does this look good?

```
&__left-cut {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 0 3px 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -8px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-left: 1px;
    background-color: $bg-color;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition: border 0.5s;

    &::before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      width: 14px;
      height: 14px;
      left: 0;
      top: 50%;
      margin-left: -3px;
      margin-top: -4px;
      background-color: $bg-color;
    }
  }

  &__right-cut {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-right: -8px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-right: 1px;
    background-color: $bg-color;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transition: border 0.5s;

    &::before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      width: 14px;
      height: 14px;
      right: 0;
      top: 50%;
      margin-right: -3px;
      margin-top: -4px;
      background-color: $bg-color;
    }
  }
```